# Android Studio 3.0 doesn't show crash logs

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

In Android Studio 2.x, "Logcat" used to show the stack trace when the app crashes. But in Android Studio 3.0, it doesn't. I don't have any filters. Options are set to "Verbose" & "No Filters".

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added another image with the full view. You *have* to filter using something in the 2nd dropdown (this is a new dropdown in Android Studio 3.0). There is no "No filter" option. I meant "No Filter" for the last dropdown.

Comment: In the top image, it says that the ADB connection is disconnected. That should only be the case when you stop the emulator

Comment: Let me upload a GIF by triggering a crash

Comment: @cricket_007 GIF added

Comment: Click `run` to try .`run` was at the bottom of `Android Studio`

Comment: I might suggest you use the debugger instead of relying on the logcat. It clearly crashes around the dialog box button event

Comment: In any case, in the device dropdown, is there multiple listed? It says "Unknown Google Nexus"... What is "Unknown" about it?

Comment: @emaillenin how did you resolve this issue, any insights please?

Comment: For some reason, it started working again.